# Webpack DllReferencePlugin is not working

Tags: webpack, dllplugin, dllreferenceplugin

I've got a problem with the ***DllReferencePlugin*** on one of my projects (I'm using *Webpack 1.13.2*). In particular, I have 3 pairs of manifests and bundle files generated by ***DllPlugin*** and in my plugins section for the main bundle I have 3 *DllReferencePlugin* sections:

```
entry: {    
  body: [
    './src/main.js',
  ],
},
...
plugins: [
...
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: process.cwd(),
      manifest: path.join(dllPath, 'commons-manifest.json'),
    }),
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: process.cwd(),
      manifest: path.join(dllPath, 'vendor-manifest.json'),
    }),
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: process.cwd(),
      manifest: path.join(dllPath, 'react-manifest.json'),
    }),    
]
...
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

> /node_modules/webpack/lib/DelegatedModuleFactoryPlugin.js:43
>                 if(request && request in this.options.content) {
>                                                      ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for './src/main.js' in
>   undefined

The same configuration works nice for my other project, so I think this error has something to do with the path resolution. I've tried relative paths for the context and manifest path but it does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that for this particular version of Webpack (1.13.2) `manifest: require(path.join(dllPath, 'commons-manifest.json'))` should be used instead of `manifest: path.join(dllPath, 'commons-manifest.json')`